# "non-terminal statement or declaration" error when using Microsoft's proprietary filter property in Sass

Tags: sass

I have the following CSS code in a SCSS file:

```
.blur{
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg height='0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='svgBlur' x='-5%' y='-5%' width='110%' height='110%'><feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='5'/></filter></svg>#svgBlur");
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius = '3');
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

But when I compile it, I get this error:

```
...
non-terminal statement or declaration must end with ';'
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between progid: and DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius = '3');

So, this should work:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius = '3');
```

:)

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Have a nice day